# Alexa test doesn't play sound

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am creating my first skill for Alexa following a Youtube channel "Alexa Developers" of the course "Building Alexa Skills from Scratch". However, after reaching the test level, I find that the skill responds with answers on screen but there is no sound at all.

Comment: Did you check the "Sound" permission of the browser? It's usually "Allowed" by default.

Comment: Where? I don't find how to enable it even if I google it. I googled "how to give sound permission of the browser for alexa"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to implement sounds, you should try using SSML features in your custom alexa skills. 
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes